# What does Google know about me when I use Chrome to browse?

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy, internet-security, tracking

Specifically, I wanted to know, when one uses Chrome to browse, assuming that they are not signed into a Google account and there are no cookies/history/cache or other data saved before starting, which of the following does Chrome send back to Google:

1. Your IP address
2. Your MAC address
3. Your User Agent
4. Your Hardware Serial Numbers
5. Other Information About OS, Hardware, Location, etc.

I even read something about a Unique ID that Google tags devices with if they come with Chrome pre-installed, and an Advertising ID as well. It seems like a bottomless pit with Google.

Comment: Long story short, if you care about privacy, don't use Chrome.

Comment: Still, I'd like to know what they know.

Comment: Tbh I wouldn't mind an answer to this question with 'Chrome' replaced with 'Firefox', 'Safari', 'Tor', whatever. I'm interested in what information browsers collect and send back to their parent companies, especially w.r.t. points 1-5.

Comment: I'd start with the Privacy Policy. https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/ But don't assume it is limited to the data mentioned there. There is also the app of course: https://www.ghacks.net/2021/03/16/wonder-about-the-data-google-collects-in-chrome-and-links-to-you-now-we-know/ Limiting it to just Chrome is slightly misleading because of course Google/Alphabet combines data from different sources. https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2021/03/20/stop-using-google-chrome-on-apple-iphone-12-pro-max-ipad-and-macbook-pro/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm going to download DuckDuckGo now.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at https://www.eff.org/pages/tools

Comment: @Gantendo I actually used their 'Cover Your Tracks' fingerprinting check. Apparently "Our tests indicate that you have strong protection against Web tracking, though your software isn’t checking for Do Not Track policies." And my browser is conveying at least 17.66 bits of information.

Comment: Google knows everything!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you do a bit but (and its true regardless of browser) As a rule -

The browser

- does not send your MAC address
- Does send your IP address.
- Does send your user agent
- Does not send other hardware serial numbers
- Sends infor.ation to facilitate inferences about OS, Hardware (largely browser string) and  Location (implied by IP address).

You may be interested in https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/ which shows what your browser leaks.

Its worth pointing out that this mainly happens because sites use things like Google Analytics for statistics- which creates a hidden/background connection to Google, as do many other "google embeds" - youtube videos, maps, reviews etc.

Its possible Google also tracks what you type in the url bar while you are typing it.